# Category guides don't show on chart Amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to add vertical guides on the category axis to show sport activities on my chart. I have a variable in my json file called UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) which is a Unix timestamp. I use this field to show on my category axis. Here is a codepen is created with my code for the chart: https://codepen.io/thomasdesaranno-r0629748/pen/jJrQgO

this is an example of my JSON file:

```
{
    "id": "NULL",
    "bg": "NULL",
    "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)": 1546603542000,
    "duration": 30,
    "sport_type": "running",
    "average_hr": 60,
    "average_speed": 30,
    "calories": 496,
    "fat_percentage_of_calories": 36,
    "food": "NULL",
    "ci": "NULL",
    "emotion": "NULL"
}
```

Does anybody know why my guides don't show?

Comment: Can you please update your code pen and add your working chart with the json data in dataLoader?

Comment: It's updated but it doesn't reallys show the charts because i have some imported libraries which i cant include

Comment: can you just add some of your data, that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sorry i forgot. Done now

Comment: Thx for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guides can not be created automatically from `dataProvider`, but you can extract the data you need and create the guides:

```
var data = [/* your data */]
var guides = data
  .map(i => i['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)'])
  .filter(i => i !== "NULL")
  .map(timestamp => ({
    "date": timestamp,
    "color": "#0000ff",
    "lineColor": "#0000ff",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "label": new Date(timestamp),
    "labelRotation": 90,
    "inside": true
  }));
```

You now can set the guides in the chart config:

```
{
  // ...
  "guides": guides,
  // ...
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLGZgo) I have created a code pen as reference.

If you want to use the `dataLoader` property to load external data for your chart you can use the `dataUpdated` event to generate the guides and add them to the chart:

```
{
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event":"dataUpdated", 
    "method": function(event) {
      event.chart.guides = event.chart.dataProvider
        .map(i => i['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)'])
        .filter(i => i !== "NULL")
        .map(timestamp => ({
          "date": timestamp,
          "color": "#0000ff",
          "lineColor": "#0000ff",
          "lineAlpha": 1,
          "label": new Date(timestamp),
          "labelRotation": 90,
          "inside": true
      }));
      event.chart.validateNow();
    }
  }],
  // ...
}
```

Don't forget to call `chart.validateNow()`, otherwise the chart don't shows the guides.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvaZWQ) I have created a code pen for the `dataLoader` solution.

In the [official docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/guide/) you can read more about guides and their configuration.